# Right Click menu on Html table in IE Displays In Left upper corner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got an existing website that I am trying to add a right-click context menu to a table by using the following plugin [jquery](https://github.com/mar10/jquery-ui-contextmenu)  the Table in my php name is "Table1" I am using the following javascript to populate the menu :

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    {
       $("#Table1").contextmenu({
       delegate: ".RightClickMenu",
       menu: [
          {title: "Add", action: function(event, ui) {
         // Do something
      }}, 
      {title: "----"},
      {title: "Refresh", action: function(event, ui) {
         // Do something
      }}
     ] 
   });
});
```

This creates a menu containing "Add" and "Refresh"(In my actual site its different menu's) when I implement this code on my website it works in Chrome(When I right click on table it displays the menu on the table where I clicked) but when I open the site using IE the menu still opens but in the upper right corner of IE... Why is this happening? what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Edit: Used the following code From the Api and now it is working... seems to be something with IE8

```
$("#StockListWorkBenchTbl").contextmenu({
   delegate: ".StockListWorkBenchTblRightClickMenu",
   menu: [
      {title: "Review Bids", action: function(event, ui) {
            var row = ui.target.parent();
            var BidID = row.attr('id');
            var selFlowStat = row.find('td:eq(2)').html();            

            CallFetchReviewBids(BidID, selFlowStat);
      }}, 
      {title: "Extend Expiry", action: function(event, ui) {
            /*var BidID = ui.target.parent().attr('id');
            var BidRow = ui.target.parent();
            ExtendExpiry(BidID, BidRow);*/

           $("#StockListWorkBenchTbl tr").each(function(){
              var BidRow = $(this);
              var BidID = BidRow.attr("id");
              var Checkbox = $(this).find("input:checkbox:first");

              if (Checkbox.attr("id") !== "StockListWorkBenchAllChecked")
              {
                 if (Checkbox.is(":checked"))
                 {
                    ExtendExpiry(BidID, BidRow);
                 }
              }
           });            
      }}, 
      {title: "----"},
      {title: "Refresh", action: function(event, ui) {
            CallToFetchWorkBench(0);
      }}
   ], 
   position: function(event, ui){
        return {my: "left top", at: "left bottom", within: ui.target};
    }
  });
```

Comment: What Version of IE? http://wwwendt.de/tech/demo/jquery-contextmenu/demo/ doesn't work at all in my IE8, but works perfectly fine in IE9. How about this demo page in your IE? Perhaps you should check whether you have to set some position according to the API specified there: https://github.com/mar10/jquery-ui-contextmenu Have you got an example of your complete page? If the demo page is working in your IE, you might want to check for differences to your script.

Comment: this is javascript, jquery, html answer not about php

Comment: removed php tag, waiting for acceptance through peer review.

Comment: @stef77 Thank you it worked.. I used the API and changed my script see the Edit. Thank you think its a IE8 thing.

Comment: I think its a css problem for #Table1

Comment: post what worked as an answer to accept, don't put the answer in the question